# Oracle PL/SQL Anonymous Block to retrieve Data from Two Tables (NOVA Environment)

Tags: oracle, plsql

Moving up in the world I'm beginning to take my first steps at PL/SQL, and I must admit I'm totally lost. Unfortunately, many of the references that I've read over haven't helped with the confusion.

In light of this, I figured I'd create a couple of basic tables and come here for the great advice that is always flowing. I seem to learn better by viewing examples and "decomposing" them to make sense in my brain.

So, on that note - could someone show me how I could develop an anonymous PL/SQL block to output some basic data from the following tables? Let's say the output should display the total number of sales where a customer purchased a Sharp TV.

Here are some tables I created:

```
CREATE TABLE TVMAKES
        (tvID     INT             PRIMARY KEY,
        tvMake    VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
        tvModel   VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE TVSALES
        (saleID      INT          PRIMARY KEY,
        tvID         INT,
CONSTRAINT SALES_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (tvID) REFERENCES TVMAKES(tvID));
```

And Here's Some data to populate the tables:

```
INSERT INTO TVMAKES (tvID,tvMake,tvModel) VALUES (1,'Sharp','50LCD');
INSERT INTO TVMAKES (tvID,tvMake,tvModel) VALUES (2,'Sony','20LCD');
INSERT INTO TVMAKES (tvID,tvMake,tvModel) VALUES (3,'Samsung','25LCD');
INSERT INTO TVMAKES (tvID,tvMake,tvModel) VALUES (4,'LG','58LCD');
INSERT INTO TVMAKES (tvID,tvMake,tvModel) VALUES (5,'Vizio','60LCD');
INSERT INTO TVMAKES (tvID,tvMake,tvModel) VALUES (6,'Sharp','30LCD');

INSERT INTO TVSALES (saleID,tvID) VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO TVSALES (saleID,tvID) VALUES (2,6);
INSERT INTO TVSALES (saleID,tvID) VALUES (3,2);
INSERT INTO TVSALES (saleID,tvID) VALUES (4,2);
INSERT INTO TVSALES (saleID,tvID) VALUES (5,3);
INSERT INTO TVSALES (saleID,tvID) VALUES (6,4);
INSERT INTO TVSALES (saleID,tvID) VALUES (7,5);
```

So just to re-iterate, could you please show me an example of an anonymous PL/SQL block to return the total sales for TV's where the tvMake is Sharp? I'm using a NOVA Oracle DB. I know it's typically not preferred to just outright "ask" for a solution here, but I'm trying to learn PL/SQL and really don't know where to start, so sometimes it's best to look at a direct example that I can easily understand to get the basics.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Forget about PL/SQL. Try to write a pure SQL SELECT that will return data you're interested in. Then, when you have it. switch to PL/SQL. In its simplest form, you'd put the above SELECT statement into a cursor FOR loop and display its values using DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE. Give it a try, someone will assist if you can't make it work.

Comment: @Littlefoot - I was with you for the first part, but then I disagree with the second part. There is no need for cursor FOR loop. The pure SQL SELECT statement is an aggregate query on top of a join and it returns just a number. The PL/SQL block should declare a single variable - the desired number - and select that total amount INTO the variable, and then display the variable. No need for any loops here; if any looping is necessary, Oracle will do it in the SQL context.

Comment: I agree, @mathguy. My idea (obviously, not very smart) was to create a query which would return ALL tvMakes and number of sales for each of them. Just to make this relatively simple task (for a newbie) a little bit more complex.

Comment: you can do this in sql, and if you can do it in sql, do it in sql 
select count(*)
from tvsales where 
tvid in (select tvid from tvmakes where tvmake = 'Sharp');

Comment: Thanks for responding. I know this can easily be accomplished (and is better accomplished IMO) by a simple select statement, however I'm coming to a point where I need to learn PL/SQL, so I figured it would be an easy example to cross-reference from standard SQL to PL/SQL. So for example, the query that @thatjeffsmith provided provides the number of sales for a Sharp tvMake. How would I "convert" that to an anonymous PL/SQL block?

Comment: Good! One thing to keep in mind though, as you are starting to learn PL/SQL. Doing things in plain SQL is still the best option in most cases, if it is an option at all. (That is, only do in PL/SQL those things that you simply can't do in plain SQL.) I personally find it dangerous to practice using loops - reading and processing one row at a time from a base table - in a PL/SQL block, instead of doing set-level processing in SQL. If you must practice loops (for example), look for tasks that CAN'T be done in SQL, at least not easily. Don't practice doing in PL/SQL tasks that are easy in SQL.

Comment: @mathguy thanks for the good advice! Notes taken!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
declare
 make integer;
 total integer;
begin
 select tvid into make from tvmakes where tvmake = 'Sharp';
 select count(*) into total from tvsales where tvid = make;
 dbms_output.put_line('We sold ' || total || ' Sharp TVs so far.');
end;
/
```

You can't just run a SQL statement in a plsql block - you need to do SOMETHNG with it. In this case we'll declare 2 local integers and populate them with the results of our 2 queries.

Then we'll use the DBMS_OUTPUT package to send a message with the results of our work.

Note that your program will have to ASK for the contents of the DBMS_OUTPUT buffer. In SQL*Plus/SQLcl/SQL Developer this is most easily accomplished by using

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

[image]

If you've made it this far, then awesome.

Now, if you really want to learn PL/SQL - and you're confident you already have a good handle on SQL, then consider our resources available at [LiveSQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:49:15065965545491:::::). You can learn and code PL/SQL from lessons/examples from there.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for a fantastic example and awesome references to go with!

Comment: you'll need an Oracle Singe Sign On account to use LiveSQL, but takes less than 5 minutes, you can stay anon, and it lets you download all db offerings from OTN as well

Comment: So I actually have one more question, and I can post it as a new question if you think that'd be the best way to address it. Say, for instance I have an additional TV in the table that is made by Sharp (tvID 6 for example). If I do that, this anonymous block would then return an error (ORA-01422). From what I can tell, if multiple rows need to be retrieved, a cursor should be implemented. How would that work into this block? Thanks again!

Comment: @StevenC you need to work on your data model first - the way it looks, you should only have 1 Make per manufacturer. So you need to think through the makes and models relationship.

Comment: Updated the question to reflect code that includes tvModel fields and an additional Sharp tvMake. Does that help?

Comment: @StevenC - the query Jeff posted in a comment under your original post will work in this more general situation (using an IN condition... and you don't need a variable for "make", you only need one for "count"). This is one of those examples where - while learning and working in PL/SQL - the answer to your modified question still lies in plain SQL, not in the PL/SQL code.